# Show VF page if opportunity amount is changed?

Tags: visualforce

I want to show a VF page if the oppy amount is changed, I got this code so far but it always shows the prompt.

```
  <script>
        if({!Opportunity.Amount})
            alert('Do not forget to update the Revenue Spread');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

I would need to add some logic so that it only prompts when the amount is changed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "show a VF page"?  You are using Javascript and the alert function will display a Javascript modal, not a Visualforce page.  Please [edit] your to to include more details and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the Salesforce stack exchange!

The script in your question will show the alert any time that the opportunity's amount is non-zero and not null. In Javascript, these values are "falsey", meaning when you put them into that if statement, the alert box will not fire (because the if statement evaluates to false). On the other hand, any other value (like $325.10) is non-zero, meaning that the alert box will show, because non-zero values are "truthy".

If you want to check if the opportunity's amount has changed, then you need to run a comparison within the if statement. Something like this:

```
let OldAmount = null; // populate this field somehow
let NewAmount = {!Opportunity.Amount};
if (NewAmount != OldAmount) {
    alert('Do not forget to update the Revenue Spread');
}
```

!= is a comparison operator in JavaScript which means "not equal to". So it's checking to see if the new value is "not equal to" the old value (i.e. if it has changed).

The question then would be, how do you determine the old amount (prior to the update) in the context of a visualforce page. In a trigger handler, you have that kind of information. In a visualforce page, I'm assuming that your page is what's performing the update to the opportunity's amount field. If that's the case, then you just need to store the old amount in a variable, so that you can compare against it later on.

Comment: Thanks Nathanael!
This was really helpful, I still couldn't quite solve the issue of storing the old amount because I'm new with all of this.
The page does not update the Oppy amount, it's the user who updates it and the pop-up should trigger so that the user does not forget to update the Revenue Spead as well.
I'll keep trying things, your help was enlightening, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. When a user updates a field in native salesforce, that isn't done on a visualforce page. That's done on a page that Salesforce creates. So the question in my mind is, how does this page relate to a user update? At what point does the user see this page, after making an update through the native salesforce user interface?

If all you want to do is make sure the user updates two fields instead of one, you might try creating a validation rule that shows an error if the amount is changed, but the revenue spread is not.

Comment: I inserted the VF page with no width or height so that the explorer that you are using gives you a pop-up like the following one https://ibb.co/HHbrgtK

The thing is that Revenue Spread is a related child record and the sum of all the related Revenue Spread records totalizes to the oppy amount so I don't think a VR rule would work here because we want to let them edit.

The idea would be, let them update the Oppy amount and remind them that they should also update the revenue spread so that the sum of them equals the Oppy amount.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not particularly familiar with that method of mounting a visualforce page, so someone else may need to comment. When I need to solve this kind of use case, I typically use something we call a "problem checkbox" -- a formula checkbox on the record that gets checked off it the data is incorrect in some way. This serves a s a reminder to the users to fix the bad data, and we are able to automate against it by disabling actions from running until the user fixes all problems. Food for thought; others will need to comment on the VF option.